# Populate table with many elements

Tags: php, html, codeigniter, html-table

I'm working on website that is using codeigniter, and I have this table that will be filled with the information from a database.
When I populate my table it takes quite some time because I have 15000 rows on my DB, and the browser gets stuck on loading for a minute or two.

Here's part of my code

View:

```
<div class="portlet-body">
                 <table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover table-full-width" id="sample_1">
                    <thead>
                       <tr>
                          <th>ID</th>
                          <th class="hidden-xs">Serial Number</th>
                          <th class="hidden-xs">Codigo</th>
                          <th class="hidden-xs">Estado</th>
                          <th class="hidden-xs">Data de inserção</th>
                          <th class="hidden-xs">Provider</th>
                       </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>   
                       <?php  foreach ($query->result_array() as $row): {                              

                        ?>
                        <tr>
                          <td><?php echo $row['product_id'] ?></td>
                          <td><?php echo $row['serial_number'] ?></td>
                          <td class="hidden-xs"><?php echo $row['product_code'] ?></td>
                          <td class="hidden-xs"><?php echo $row['product_status'] ?></td>
                          <td class="hidden-xs"><?php echo $row['product_insertion_date'] ?></td>
                          <td class="hidden-xs"><?php echo $row['product_provider'] ?></td>
                       </tr>

                       <?php }  endforeach; ?>

                    </tbody>
                 </table>
              </div>
```

Controller:

```
public function loadProdutos(){

    $this->load->model('produtos_model'); 
    $tmp = $this->produtos_model->getProdutos();

    $data['query'] = $tmp;


    $this->load->view('produtos',$data);
}
```

Model:

```
function getProdutos() {

    $query = $this->db->get('products');
    return $query;  
}
```

My question is, if there is a best practice in this kind of situation, or some other way of doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**First option**

You might want to try and put a pagination in there, so the results are split into different pages and are not loaded all at once.

Codeigniter provides a [pagination](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter%20/user-guide/libraries/pagination.html) in their libraries:

**Second option**

You can also try to put an ajax load in there, when you reach the bottom of the page, although this might be a bit harder to do.

You can find a tutorial [here](http://developer-paradize.blogspot.be/2013/06/how-to-make-pagination-class-in.html), or search around on google to find one that suits you.

**Third option**

A load more button, that is similar to the one above, but without the 'if you reach the bottom of the page'

If you need any help at implementing those, let me know and I'll help as much as possible.
If neither of these three options are something you want, then I'm out of ideas too.

Answer (score 0):

Your easiest and quickest solution is probably to use [pagination](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/pagination.html). This will reduce the server load as well as the load on the browser as it only has to display a few rows at a time rather than all 15,000.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of getting all the results you should limit the results using pagination, so something like 20 results returned per page. Check out how CodeIgnitor handles this for other views as this should be reasonably well built it.

As a starting point you can refer to this doc - http://ellislab.com/codeigniter%20/user-guide/libraries/pagination.html

Answer (score 0):

What you need is pagination, you can implement this very easily with DataTables with data_source ajax: http://datatables.net/examples/data_sources/ajax.html

And what you also can do is gzip the content. When you output 15.000 rows, you probably have a request with a size of a couple of megabytes.. When you gzip this, it will go radically smaller..

But still, the best update is pagination.

Answer (score 0):

you can use pagination option. it is the better choice to load data if the db has more rows. because it loads per page only.